# Showing that $f$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, implicit-function-theorem

**Question:**

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function, with $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ open, such that $$(x^2  +y^4)f(x,y) + f(x,y)^3 = 1,\, \,\, \forall (x,y) \in U$$
>   Show that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$.

**Attempt:**

Define $F(x,y,z) = (x^2 + y^4)z + z^3 - 1$. Then $$F_z(x,y,z) = (x^2 + y^4) + 3z^2 > 0$$

for any $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3- \{0\}$, and if we fix $(x_0,y_0) \in U$, such that $(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$, then taking $z_0 = f(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb R$, thus it follows that $F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = 0$.

Now by the Implicit Function Theorem we have that $z$ is a defined as a function of $x$ and $y$, such that $$F(x,y,z) = F(x,y,\xi (x,y)) = 0 \tag{1}$$ for every $(x,y,z) \in B \times J$, here $B \subset \mathbb R^2$ and $J \subset \mathbb R$. Clearly $F$ is of class $C^\infty$ then $z = \xi (x,y)$ is of class $C^\infty$.

As $f$ is continuous there exists $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small such that $f(B) \subseteq J$, then we may conclude by $(1)$ and by hypothesis $F(x,y,f(x,y)) = 0$, that  $f(x,y) = \xi(x,y)$, for every $x \in B$, it follows then that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$.

Comment: One thing I would mention is that you do not need to explicitly exclude the case $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$. Since in this case you must have $z_0 = f(x_0,y_0) = 1$, and so $F_z(x_0,y_0,z_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, finally someone has answered what I asked. I haven't noticed that. Thank you ver much.

Answer (score 1):

For $t\ge 0$ the function $z \mapsto z^3 + t z -1$ is strictly increasing, with limit $+ \infty ( -\infty ) $ at $ + \infty ( - \infty)$. Therefore, for every fixed $t \ge 0$ the equation $z^3 + t z - 1 = 0$ has a unique solution $z(t)$. Note that $0 < z(t) \le 1$ for every $t \ge 0$ and $t \mapsto z(t)$ is strictly decreasing.  For instance, $z(0) = 1$. Let's show that $t \mapsto z(t)$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function. Indeed, whenever we have $z^3 + t z - 1 = 0$ the derivative $\frac{\partial (z^3 + t z - 1) }{\partial z} = 3 z^2 + t >0$ so it's not zero. Using the implicit function theorem we conclude that around any $t\ge0$ the unique solution $z(t)$ is a smooth function. Hence $[0, \infty)\ni t \mapsto z(t) \in  (0, 1]$, being locally smooth, is smooth.

It's worth noticing that we have an explicit formula ( the equation being of degree $3$)

$$z(t) = \left( \sqrt{ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{t^3}{27}} + \frac{1}{2} \right )^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( \sqrt{ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{t^3}{27}} - \frac{1}{2} \right )^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Now we get $f(x,y) = z[ x^2 + y^4]$, a composition of smooth functions, hence smooth.

Let's point out that unless we specify some continuity for $f(x,y)$, we need to use the uniqueness of the real solution of some equation. For instance, the functional equation $f(x,y)^2 - (x^2 + y^4+1)$ also has dincontinuous solutions, since $z^2 - t=0$ has two solutions $\pm \sqrt{t}$ for $t > 0$

Comment: What about my approach?

Comment: @Aaron Maroja: Ah, if $f$ is assumed continuous then you are fine, yes.

Comment: It's in the hypothesis, yes. Thanks, I was wondering if my approach was correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aaron Maroja: Yes, if you have the hypothesis of the implicit function theorem and you assume that you have a continuous solution, then the solution is  smooth.  Or, if you know that the solution is unique. In you case, both hypothesis are satisfied.  Make sure that you use that extra you have. Since the implicit function theorem tells you that you have a smooth solution around a point but you have to see that $f$ coincides with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of $P(z) = t z + z^3 - 1$ is $-4 t^3 - 27$, which is nonzero for $t \ge 0$.  Thus $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} P(z) \ne 0$ whenever $P(z) = 0$ with $t \ge 0$.  In particular, this applies when $t = x^2 + y^4$.